# SUMIF Query Returning One Line

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database like facebook. A query asks me to count how many Male friends, Female friends and Null friends (no sex specificated).

I have this query so far, but it only returns 1 row, not all the users.

```
create or replace view friends as

select  fs.user_id,
        fs.user_id_friend,
        sum(if(fs.sex = 'M', 1, 0)) as Male_Friends,
        sum(if(fs.sex = 'F', 1, 0)) as Female_Friends,
        sum(if(fs.sex = ' ', 1, 0)) as Friends_Undefined_Sex
from friends_sex fs;
```

This prints me only one row ans I need it to print all the users, can anyone please help me out?

If you need more info about the tables or views ask for it, I'm quite new to this forum so excuse me for any mistakes.

Comment: `GROUP BY fs.user_id`

Comment: Can you post some sample data along with expected output?

Comment: A sample output should be something like this;

USER_ID | MALE_FRIENDS | FEMALE_FRIENDS | FRIENDS_UNDEFINED_SEX
1 | 5 | 2 | 4
2 | 4| 3 | 2

I don't need the user_id_friend column, it was just for testing.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos why you delete your answer?

Comment: I got it already! Thanks to everyone.

Comment: @NilMartiHermans If an answer solved your problem, please *mark it as accepted.*  Do not just update the title of your question to say `[SOLVED]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is malformed.  The problem is that you have columns in the `select` (such as 'fs.user_id`) that are not in the`group by`.  This is allowed in MySQL, but not in other databases.  It tends to just cause confusion.

Because of the aggregation functions, the query is an aggregation query.  Without a `group by` it returns one row.  So you need a `group by`:

```
select  fs.user_id,
        sum(fs.sex = 'M') as Male_Friends,
        sum(fs.sex = 'F') as Female_Friends,
        sum(fs.sex = ' ') as Friends_Undefined_Sex
from friends_sex fs
group by fs.user_id;
```

Note that in MySQL you don't need `if()`.  MySQL treats booleans as integers in integer contexts, with "1" for true and "0" for false.

Also note that there is no `fs.user_id_friend` to return; presumably, many people have more than one friend.  If you want a list, then include:

```
group_concat(fs.user_id_friend)
```

to get a comma-delimited list of the friends' ids.

Answer (score 1):

Is there only one friend in the table? :)  you are missing a `group by` command in your query to tell sql you want the results by user, also remove the `fs.user_id_friend` from your `select` statement or you are telling sql you want one row for every friend in which case all of the columns will never be greater than 1.  You can also `count` `fs.user_id_friend` if you want a total `count` of friends.

```
create or replace view friends as

select  fs.user_id,
        count(fs.user_id_friend) AS NumberOfFriends,
        sum(if(fs.sex = 'M', 1, 0)) as Male_Friends,
        sum(if(fs.sex = 'F', 1, 0)) as Female_Friends,
        sum(if(fs.sex = ' ', 1, 0)) as Friends_Undefined_Sex
from friends_sex fs
GROUP BY fs.user_id;
```

Comment: I think that is just what i need, I'll try it out. Like i said i don't need the fs.user_id_friend column, it was just for testing.

Comment: got it hope it helps you

Comment: your welcome if you don't mind accepting my answer seeing it worked for you it would be much appreciated thnaks!